# Node js Request body type is [Object, Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to send a request with a custom string value to the server with express and body-parser in Node.js, but I get the following when I try to inspect the posted value.

> [object Object]

Server -

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.post('/', callback)

function callback(req, res) {
  console.log('post/' + req.body)
  res.send('post success!')
}
```

Client -

```
var request = require('request')
request.post({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
  body: 'testing'
}, function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err)
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body)
})
```

---

Client logs -

> Upload successful!  Server responded with: post success!

Server logs -

> post/[object Object]

how can I get the string content `"testing"` instead?
Thank you!

Comment: remove the `toString()` off from `req.body`.

Comment: tried using `JSON.stringify` on it, or `console.dir` instead of `.log`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to post via [form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) - which through [`request`[forms]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms) - will apply the appropriate `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` http header. Observe the following...

```
// -- notice the keyed object being sent
request.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', {
  form: {customKey: 'testing'}
}, function (err, httpResponse, body) {

  console.log(body); // post success!
});
```

On your endpoint, if you want to log this out you can then do so as such...

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {

  console.log('post/ ', req.body.customKey'); // -- post/ testing
  res.send('post success!');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see [object Object] content in console.log try this:

```
const util = require('util');
...
console.log(`post/${util.inspect(req.body,false,null)}`);
```

More info: [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is with [console.dir()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) instead of console.log().

> The Console method dir() displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical listing with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of child objects.
>
> In other words, console.dir() is the way to see all the properties of
>   a specified JavaScript object in console by which the developer can
>   easily get the properties of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a validation middleware.. and hence this was an issue.
the validator was ..

```
BookingBodyValidation: [
    sanitizeBody("*")
      .trim()
      .escape(),
    body("refNo").notEmpty()
  ]
```

removing this "sanitizeBody().trim().escape()" solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might find this handy... for the server-side, I wrote a little JS snippet that parses out the key/value pairs of an incoming **req.body** (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and displays them on the console as a valid JSON object:

```
const util=require('util');let s=util.inspect(req.body)
.split(`Content-Disposition: form-data; name`);s.splice(0,1);
let r=`{"`;s.forEach((e)=>{r+=e.split(`\\r\\n------`)[0]
.replace(`"\\r\\n\\r\\n`,`":"`).replace(`\': \'"`,``)
.replace(`=`,``)+`",`});s=r.slice(0,-1)+`}`;console.log(s);
```